# ERROR google.cloud.speech from google.cloud.speech import enums ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'

Tags: python, enums, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

refer to url
[ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511406/importerror-cannot-import-name-enums)

[google cloud speech ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800281/google-cloud-speech-importerror-cannot-import-name-enums)

I got the error when using google-cloud-speech api for my project. I'm NOT using pipenv for virtual environment. I installed google-cloud-speech api with

```
pip3 install google-cloud-speech
```

and

```
pip3 update google-cloud-speech
```

environment
win10
python3.6.8

google-api-core                  1.14.2

google-auth                      1.6.3

google-cloud                     0.34.0

google-cloud-core                1.0.3

google-cloud-speech              1.2.0

google-cloud-storage             1.18.0

google-resumable-media           0.3.3

googleapis-common-protos         1.6.0

grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1beta1 1.0.1

enum34                           1.1.6
enums                            0.0.2

the error contents

```
from google.cloud.speech import enums
ImportError: cannot import name 'enums'
```

I already tried the pip command follow.

```
pip3 install enums
pip3 install enum34

pip3 install google-cloud-speech 
pip3 upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

here the code when the code did in google cloud shell of GCP, the following code works well and I didn't get the error.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import argparse
import io
import sys
import codecs
import datetime
import locale
from google.cloud import storage

from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types


def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC, # wavsetting
        sample_rate_hertz=44100, # hertz must be fix raw files
        language_code='ja-JP') #for japanese language

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    operationResult = operation.result()

    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    today = d.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    fout = codecs.open('output{}.txt'.format(today), 'a', 'utf-8')

    for result in operationResult.results:
      for alternative in result.alternatives:
          fout.write(u'{}\n'.format(alternative.transcript))
          print('alternative.transcript===',format(alternative.transcript))
    fout.close()

    print('alternative.transcript===',format(alternative.transcript))
    print('operationResult===',operationResult)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        'path', help='GCS path for audio file to be recognized')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    transcribe_gcs(args.path)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `... import enums as genums` works?

Comment: i tried that code but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

By using pip install google.cloud.speech, you are getting the latest version, currently V2.

In V2, enums and types have been removed and are no longer needed.

https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#enums-and-types

Answer (score 0):

Should be: `from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums`

Comment: It was just as you say that.I overlooked the code to add the version of gcs.Thanks lots Brendan.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

```
from google.cloud.language_v1 import *
```

Then you can access all of followings directly

```
LanguageServiceAsyncClient
AnalyzeEntitiesRequest
AnalyzeEntitiesResponse
AnalyzeEntitySentimentRequest
AnalyzeEntitySentimentResponse
AnalyzeSentimentRequest
AnalyzeSentimentResponse
AnalyzeSyntaxRequest
AnalyzeSyntaxResponse
AnnotateTextRequest
AnnotateTextResponse
ClassificationCategory
ClassifyTextRequest
ClassifyTextResponse
DependencyEdge
Document
EncodingType
Entity
EntityMention
LanguageServiceClient
PartOfSpeech
Sentence
Sentiment
TextSpan
Token
```